# Join Postgresql rows with Mongodb documents based on specific columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mongodb, postgresql

I'm using MongoDB and PostgreSQL in my application. The need of using MongoDB is we might have any number of new fields that would get inserted for which we'll store data in MongoDB.

We are storing our fixed field values in PostgreSQL and custom field values in MongoDB.

```
E.g.

**Employee Table (RDBMS):**
id       Name       Salary
1        Krish      40000

**Employee Collection (MongoDB):**
{
    <some autogenerated id of mongodb>
    instanceId: 1 (The id of SQL: MANUALLY ASSIGNED),
    employeeCode: A001
}
```

We get the records from SQL, and from their ids, we fetch related records from MongoDB. Then map the result to get the values of new fields and send on UI.

Now I'm searching for some optimized solution to get the MongoDB results in PostgreSQL POJO / Model so I don't have to fetch the data manually from MongoDB by passing ids of SQL and then mapping them again.

Is there any way through which I can connect MongoDB with PostgreSQL through columns (Here Id of RDBMS and instanceId of MongoDB) so that with one fetch, I can get related Mongo result too. Any kind of return type is acceptable but I need all of them at one call.

I'm using Hibernate and Spring in my application.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that Postgres couldn't support schema flexibility without resorting to creating an abomination, i.e.: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html

Comment: @Sammaye *much* better to use the json support in 9.3 / 9.4.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) might be the best solution for your use case, since it supports both:

- JPA
- MongoDB

You can still get all data in one request but that doesn't mean you have to use a single DB call. You can have one service call which spans to twp database calls. Because the PostgreSQL row is probably the primary entity, I advise you to  share the PostgreSQL primary key with MongoDB too.

There's no need to have separate IDs. This way you can simply fetch the SQL and the Mongo document by the same ID. Sharing the same ID can give you the advantage of processing those requests concurrently and merging the result prior to returning from the service call. So the service method duration will not take the sum of the two Repositories calls, being the max of these to calls.

Answer (score 1):

Astonishingly, yes, you potentially can. There's a [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) named [`mongo_fdw`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#mongo_fdw) that allows PostgreSQL to query MongoDB. I haven't used it and have no opinion as to its performance, utility or quality.

I would be very surprised if you could effectively use this via Hibernate, unless you can convince Hibernate that the FDW mapped "tables" are just views. You might have more luck with [EclipseLink and their "NoSQL" support](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_nosql.htm) if you want to do it at the Java level.

Separately, this sounds like a monstrosity of a design. There are many sane ways to do what you want within a decent RDBMS, without going for a hybrid database platform. There's a time and a place for hybrid, but I really doubt your situation justifies the complexity.

[Just use PostgreSQL's `json` / `jsonb` support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to support dynamic mappings. Or use traditional options like storing `json` as text fields, storing XML, or even EAV mapping. Don't build a [rube goldberg machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine).